# How can I get a noob slide for full page width?

Tags: jquery, css, mootools

I'm trying to create a full page noobslide for my website. I tried changing the width to 100% in *style.css* its not working.

here is the copy of the sample I'm working on.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39803954/noobslide_demo/index.html

Comment: tried that. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change one or two things depending on what you're going for:

1. In style.css on line 67 replace `width: 600px` with `width: 100%`
2. If you need to make changes to the width of the actual content slides, you can edit that in style.css on line 5, by changing `width: 600px` to whatever you need it to be.

If this doesn't work, make the changes and leave a comment.